# Casting a boolean array in Java?

Tags: java, casting, boolean

Is there anything I can cast a boolean array to in Java? It would be nice if I could say

```
boolean[] bools = new boolean[8];
int j = (int)bools;
```

But I'm not sure if that's feasible in Java.

Comment: Do want to treat the boolean array as a bit pattern and convert to the int value of the pattern?

Comment: Are you trying to get the pointer to the boolean array?

Comment: What's your expectation of how an array of booleans is mapped to an integer?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this with a `boolean[]` - but it sounds like you might want a [`BitSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) which is a compact representation of a set of Boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a bit pattern, I think you're better off using bitmasks e.g.

```
final int BIT_1 = 0x00000001;
final int BIT_2 = 0x00000002;

// represents a bit mask
int value;

// enable bit 2
value |= BIT_2

// switch off bit 1
value &= ~BIT_1

// do something if bit 1 is set...
if (value & BIT_1) {
```

etc. See [here](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) for more examples.

Comment: Could you add more detail on the etc part?

Answer (score 3):

the size of Java booleans is implementation specific, and it's probably not a single bit in any case.
if you want an easy way to manipulate bits, take a look at [BitSet](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Comment: They are not only implementation specific, but almost always full "int" size (or, more accurately, machine word size).  To not do it this way would slow down your system.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one quick-and-dirty way to convert from a `boolean[]` to an integer:

```
static int intFromBooleanArray(boolean[] array) {
    return new BigInteger(Arrays.toString(array)
                          .replace("true", "1")
                          .replace("false", "0")
                          .replaceAll("[^01]", ""), 2).intValue();
}
```

example:

```
intFromBooleanArray(new boolean[] {true, false, true, false, true, false});
// => 42.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `boolean[]` to `Object`, but that's about it.